# Generalization of $1988$ IMO #6

Tags: contest-math, diophantine-equations, vieta-jumping

$1988$ IMO Problem 6 states:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $ab + 1$ divides $a^2 + b^2$. Show that
> $$\frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab + 1}$$
> is the square of an integer.

My question is: what if $a$ and $b$ don't need to be positive? What other values of $\frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab + 1}$ are possible? I found a way to get $-5$ by setting $a = -1$ and $b = 2$. Is there a simple classification of such reachable integers?

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your question. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Also, simulation seems suggesting that $-5$ is the only possible negative integer value the expression $\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$ can only assume.

Comment: You can reformulate it in a similar way. If $\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$ is a negative integer, then $ab<0$. W.l.o.g. let $a<0$ and $a':=-a$, then $-\frac{a'^2+b^2}{-a'b+1}=\frac{a'^2+b^2}{a'b-1}$ is a positive integer. Hence, you can reformulate: Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers, such that $ab-1$ divides $a^2+b^2$. Is $\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab-1}$ equal five? Hopefully, we can do vieta jumping again.

Comment: The answer is always -5 for a,b>=-10000. See https://go.dev/play/p/aTeSLXPPGKX for runnable online code.

Comment: There is some stuff written on wikipedia about this problem which might be of interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping

Comment: You get infinitely many pairs $(a_n,b_n)$ for which that ratio equals $-5$, by the recursion
$$a_{n+1}=-b_n,\qquad\text{ and }\qquad b_{n+1}=5b_n+a_n,$$
starting from $(a_0,b_0)=(-1,2)$.

Comment: There is a solution to this problem at the following web site: https://brilliant.org/wiki/vieta-root-jumping/. Scroll down to the part written by Ariel Gershon. I thought about copying that into the answer box here, but it got  a bit boring.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250172/when-is-fa-b-fraca2b21ab-a-perfect-square-rational-number/250187#250187

Comment: So, the only numbers possible are the squares and -5.

Comment: @SuzuHirose  I put an answer with a nice picture. The idea of writing things this way  comes from http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to graph everything. The thing that Vieta Jumping does is to guarantee a point (if there are any integer points)  on a short arc of the hyperbola. Then  inequalities based on the size of $n$ tell us whether there can be any such integer points.

Here $$  \frac{x^2 + y^2}{xy-1}  = n $$
with $x,y > 0.$
[image]

If there are any integer points at all,  there are jumped integer points  that lie on the arc between the endpoints
$$  \left( \; \sqrt{\frac{4n}{n^2-4}} \; , \; \;  \sqrt{\frac{n^3}{n^2-4}} \; \; \right) $$
and
$$  \left( \; \sqrt{\frac{n^3}{n^2-4}} \; , \; \;  \sqrt{\frac{4n}{n^2-4}} \; \; \right) $$

One must consider $n=3,4$ separately. For $n= 5$  there are indeed integer points  at $(1,2) , \; \;  (2,1).$

For $n \geq 6$   we see the picture below (done with $n=16.$  The axis of symmetry $y=x$  meets the hyperbola at $(t,t)$  where $t = \sqrt{   \frac{n}{n-2}},$  between $1$ and $2$

For $x \geq \sqrt{   \frac{n}{n-2}},$  but $x \leq  \sqrt{\frac{n^3}{n^2-4}} , $  we see that $y$ is decreasing.  Furthermore, for $x = 2$  we find
$$ y_2 =  \frac{n+4}{n+\sqrt{n^2 - n - 4}}  .$$
Thus, for
$$ 2 \leq x  \leq   \sqrt{\frac{n^3}{n^2-4}}$$
we see $0 < y \leq \frac{n+4}{n+\sqrt{n^2 - n - 4}} .$  For $n \geq 6$ this is smaller than $1$

So that's it:  we can jump an integer point to an integer point  along a certain bounded arc of the hyperbola. Then, for $n \geq 6$  we see there are no integer points within that arc. So, no integer points at all.